# Staying DRY while re-using gulp task. How is this normally handled?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a Gulp task which spins up a local server with `gulp-connect` and then opens a browser window to interact with the server through `open`.

The code looks like this:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const connect = require('gulp-connect');
const open = require('open');
const path = require('path');

// Create a local server for hosting the project.
// Responds to livereload commands so file changes don't require refreshing.
gulp.task('connect', (done) => {
  const host = 'localhost';
  const port = 8080;

  connect.server({
    host,
    port,
    // Needs to be path.resolve and not just './'
    // https://github.com/AveVlad/gulp-connect/issues/54
    root: path.resolve('./'),
    livereload: true
  });

  // Open default browser to the compiled directory.
  // Presumably useful since a connect server was just spun up for development.
  open(`http://${host}:${port}/compiled/`);
  done();
});
```

Currently, this function only supports opening to the browser to the `compiled` directory. I would like to extend it so that I can optionally open to the `dist` directory.

It's worth noting that I'm not calling the `connect` task directly from the command line. Instead, I'm running other tasks, such as `build`, which would like to convey to `connect` its desire to open to the `dist` directory:

```
gulp.task('build', (done) => {
    // TODO: Have connect open to 'dist' and not 'compiled'
    runSequence('compile', 'build', 'connect', done);
});
```

I saw a few posts on passing command line arguments into Gulp tasks, but I don't think this is relevant due to the fact I'm not running the command explicitly from the command line, but I could be incorrect.

What's the proper way to dynamically configure this task?

EDIT: This works, but feels hacky:

```
const argv = require('yargs').argv;

const directoryName = argv._[0] === 'build' ? 'dist' : 'compiled';
open(`http://${host}:${port}/${directoryName}/`);
```

Comment: There are many solutions to this. You can pass arguments, create separate gulp tasks, or use an environment variable to name a few. Are you not running `gulp build` from the command line?

Comment: If I separate the logic for 'open' into another task then it becomes difficult to reuse the host/port variables and it feels a bit odd to create an entirely new task to change one variable.

I am running gulp build from the command line, but I'd rather not have to specify an additional parameter. It should be implicit based on the fact that gulp build is running rather than 'gulp build --dist=true' and when playing with 'yargs' it seems to expect additional params to be passed to it.

Comment: Are you using that `--dist` flag elsewhere in your gulpfile?

Comment: No. It was a hypothetical --dist flag. The only commands I run are "gulp" and "gulp build" where the default task moves files into the compiled directory and the build task moves files into the dist directory.

Answer (score 0):

Since the connect task has nothing to do with gulp, you can refactor it into a function, which you call from your other tasks.

```
function connect(dir) {
  const host = 'localhost';
  const port = 8080;

  connect.server({
    host,
    port,
    root: path.resolve('./'),
    livereload: true
  });

  open(`http://${host}:${port}/${dir}/`);
}


gulp.task('build', (done) => {
    runSequence('compile', 'task2', 'task3', () => {
        connect('dist');
        done();
    });
});
```

The downside to this solution is that you can't run `gulp connect` from the command line. But it would be trivial to create a `connect` task that uses the function above if you wanted that.